# Can't create a ECS FARGATE_SPOT using Terraform's ECS module

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-fargate

I'm learning Terraform and I'm trying to create a ECS Fargate Spot using the [AWS ECS module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/ecs/aws/latest) on Terraform.

Here is the HCL script that I'm running:

```
module "ecs" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/ecs/aws"
  version = "5.7.2"

  cluster_name = "ecs-test"

  fargate_capacity_providers = {
    FARGATE = {
      default_capacity_provider_strategy = {
        weight = 50
      }
    }
    FARGATE_SPOT = {
      default_capacity_provider_strategy = {
        weight = 50
      }
    }
  }

  services = {
    my_app = {
      name          = "my_app_service"
      cpu           = 256
      memory        = 512
      desired_count = 1

      capacity_provider_strategies = [
        {
          capacity_provider = "FARGATE_SPOT"
          base              = 0
          weight            = 1
        }
      ]

      # Task definition
      container_definitions = {
        postgres = {
          cpu       = 256
          memory    = 512
          essential = true
          image     = "my_app_image"

          port_mappings = [
            {
              name          = "my-app-port"
              containerPort = 123
              protocol      = "tcp"
            }
          ]
        }
      }

      # Network
      subnet_ids = [
        "subnet-123",
      ]

      security_group_rules = {
        egress_all = {
          type        = "egress"
          from_port   = 0
          to_port     = 0
          protocol    = "-1"
          cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
        }
      }

      assign_public_ip = true
    }
  }
}
```

When I apply the script above (with `terraform apply`), the cluster, the service and everything are created properly in my AWS account, however when I check the configuration of my service it's a normal `FARGATE` instance:

[image]

If I create a new service **manually**, using the AWS UI interface, I can create a `FARGATE_SPOT` without any problem, and it looks like this when I check the service's Configuration tab (expected result):

[image]

Question: what am I doing wrong in my HCL script above? I want to use Terraform's ECS module to create a service with capacity provider = `FARGATE_SPOT`.

Comment: Looking at the code for that module, it's doing some really convoluted stuff to set the launch type based on the capacity provider settings. It doesn't seem to allow you to simply set the launch type directly. If you want to learn Terraform I highly suggest just creating the AWS resources yourself with the AWS Terraform provider, especially for an ECS service. This module isn't saving you much code. I only really recommend using the VPC module: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws/latest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `capacity_provider_strategies` in your `services` map, but that's not actually a valid input. It should be `capacity_provider_strategy`. Please see [this line](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-ecs/blob/v5.7.2/main.tf#L60) of the module documentation on how it uses its inputs for `services`.